# Customer Cell returns nil when unwrapping an Optional Value

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a custom table view cell. In the story board, I have implemented a `UILabel` and a `UIButton`. I want to give the label a different value everytime it is reused. The storyboard connections are good. If I use `cell.textLabel.text = episodeTitle` then that works, but if I set the text property of my `UILabel` then I get the error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I have tried registering a class but that doesn't work. Not sure what to do anymore. There are tons of similar posts on SO but none helped.

This is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   //tableView.registerClass(episodeCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "episode")
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("episode", forIndexPath: indexPath) as episodeCell

    cell = episodeCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "episode")

    let episode: MWFeedItem? = episodesToDisplay.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? MWFeedItem
    if episode != nil {
        //process the episode
        var episodeTitle: NSString = episode?.title as String!
        //cell.textLabel.text = episodeTitle
       cell.episodeTitle.text = episodeTitle
    }

    return cell
}
```

and this is my custom cell:

```
class episodeCell: UITableViewCell {

var progress: Float?


@IBOutlet weak var episodeTitle: UILabel!

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("episode", forIndexPath: indexPath) as episodeCell

cell = episodeCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "episode")
```

you dequeue a cell and assign to the `cell` variable, and next you replace that instance with a brand new one. Remove this line:

```
cell = episodeCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "episode")
```